# SQL Server INSERT ... SELECT Statement won't parse

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am getting the following error message with SQL Server 2005

> Msg 120, Level 15, State 1, Procedure usp_AttributeActivitiesForDateRange, Line 18
>   The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.

I have copy and pasted the select list and insert list into excel and verified there are the same number of items in each list.  Both tables an additional primary key field with is not listed in either the insert statement or select list.  I am not sure if that is relevant, but suspicious it may be.  Here is the source for my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_AttributeActivitiesForDateRange]
(
    @dtmFrom DATETIME,
    @dtmTo DATETIME
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @dtmToWithTime DATETIME

    SET @dtmToWithTime = DATEADD(hh, 23, DATEADD(mi, 59, DATEADD(s, 59, @dtmTo)));

    -- Get uncontested DC activities

    INSERT INTO AttributedDoubleClickActivities
        ([Time],
        [User-ID],
        [IP],
        [Advertiser-ID],
        [Buy-ID],
        [Ad-ID],
        [Ad-Jumpto],
        [Creative-ID],
        [Creative-Version],
        [Creative-Size-ID],
        [Site-ID],
        [Page-ID],
        [Country-ID],
        [State Province],
        [Areacode],
        [OS-ID],
        [Domain-ID],
        [Keyword],
        [Local-User-ID],
        [Activity-Type],
        [Activity-Sub-Type],
        [Quantity],
        [Revenue],
        [Transaction-ID],
        [Other-Data],
        Ordinal,
        [Click-Time],
        [Event-ID]) SELECT 
            [Time],
            [User-ID],
            [IP],
            [Advertiser-ID],
            [Buy-ID],
            [Ad-ID],
            [Ad-Jumpto],
            [Creative-ID],
            [Creative-Version],
            [Creative-Size-ID],
            [Site-ID],
            [Page-ID],
            [Country-ID],
            [State Province],
            [Areacode],
            [OS-ID],
            [Domain-ID],
            [Keyword],
            [Local-User-ID]
            [Activity-Type],
            [Activity-Sub-Type],
            [Quantity],
            [Revenue],
            [Transaction-ID],
            [Other-Data],
            REPLACE(Ordinal, '?', '') AS Ordinal,
            [Click-Time],
            [Event-ID]
        FROM Activity_Reports
            WHERE [Time] BETWEEN @dtmFrom AND @dtmTo
            AND REPLACE(Ordinal, '?', '') IN 
        (SELECT REPLACE(Ordinal, '?', '') FROM Activity_Reports 
            WHERE [Time] BETWEEN @dtmFrom AND @dtmTo
        EXCEPT
        SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, TripID) FROM VisualSciencesActivities
            WHERE [Time] BETWEEN @dtmFrom AND @dtmTo);

END
GO
```

Comment: Isn't the point of writing your SQL insert in that, each field on it's own line, fashion so you can see exactly what line (Line 18( the error was on? =P.

Comment: A key point of "one line per column" is to make it easier to correlate what value is being inserted into one column. Imagine that blob if the columns were just dumped onto a single line, and you had to modify or insert something. (For very long sets like this one, I outdent every fifth line to simplify this.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are missing a comma between `[Local-User-ID]` and `[Activity-Type]`.

Try:

```
INSERT INTO attributeddoubleclickactivities 
            ([Time], 
             [User-ID], 
             [IP], 
             [Advertiser-ID], 
             [Buy-ID], 
             [Ad-ID], 
             [Ad-Jumpto], 
             [Creative-ID], 
             [Creative-Version], 
             [Creative-Size-ID], 
             [Site-ID], 
             [Page-ID], 
             [Country-ID], 
             [State Province], 
             [Areacode], 
             [OS-ID], 
             [Domain-ID], 
             [Keyword], 
             [Local-User-ID], 
             [Activity-Type], 
             [Activity-Sub-Type], 
             [Quantity], 
             [Revenue], 
             [Transaction-ID], 
             [Other-Data], 
             ordinal, 
             [Click-Time], 
             [Event-ID]) 
SELECT [Time], 
       [User-ID], 
       [IP], 
       [Advertiser-ID], 
       [Buy-ID], 
       [Ad-ID], 
       [Ad-Jumpto], 
       [Creative-ID], 
       [Creative-Version], 
       [Creative-Size-ID], 
       [Site-ID], 
       [Page-ID], 
       [Country-ID], 
       [State Province], 
       [Areacode], 
       [OS-ID], 
       [Domain-ID], 
       [Keyword], 
       [Local-User-ID],
       [Activity-Type], 
       [Activity-Sub-Type], 
       [Quantity], 
       [Revenue], 
       [Transaction-ID], 
       [Other-Data], 
       REPLACE(ordinal, '?', '') AS ordinal, 
       [Click-Time], 
       [Event-ID] 
FROM   activity_reports 
WHERE  [Time] BETWEEN @dtmFrom AND @dtmTo 
       AND REPLACE(ordinal, '?', '') IN (SELECT REPLACE(ordinal, '?', '') 
                                         FROM   activity_reports 
                                         WHERE  [Time] BETWEEN 
                                                @dtmFrom AND @dtmTo 
                                         EXCEPT 
                                         SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, tripid) 
                                         FROM   visualsciencesactivities 
                                         WHERE  [Time] BETWEEN 
                                                @dtmFrom AND @dtmTo);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I agonized over this for quite a while before posting.

Comment: I did this all the time, until I started using "commas first" format (i.e.    ,[OS-Id]   ). Makes those missing commas jump right out.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing a comma here:

```
[Local-User-ID] [Activity-Type]
```

Should be:

```
[Local-User-ID], [Activity-Type]
```

Answer (score 1):

you forgot a comma after   [Local-User-ID] so it aliased that column as [Activity-Type]

common mistake

in essence you have Local-User-ID] AS [Activity-Type], the AS is optional

Answer (score 0):

You don't have enough fields in your select list for the insert statement you gave.

Answer (score 0):

In the Select there is a typo

```
[Local-User-ID]
            [Activity-Type],
```

you are missing ","!